# Ngx Image Cropper Transform scale not smooth

Tags: javascript, angular

I have implemented Ngx Image cropper with a range slider, After selecting image I want the image in the cropper to be zoom in and out while i am dragging the range bar.

I have followed this example - https://stackblitz.com/edit/image-cropper?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Right now it is working but the animation is not smooth, it is jerking too much. really appreciate any help.

```
<image-cropper
class="main-cropper"
[imageChangedEvent]="imageChangedEvent"
[maintainAspectRatio]="true"
[alignImage]="center"
[aspectRatio]="1.2 / 2"
[transform]="transform"
format="png"
(imageCropped)="imageCropped($event)"
(imageLoaded)="imageLoaded()"
(cropperReady)="cropperReady()"
(loadImageFailed)="loadImageFailed()"
></image-cropper>

<nouislider [min]="0" [max]="100" [step]="1" [(ngModel)]="value" (ngModelChange)="onZoom($event)" [disabled]="disabled"></nouislider>

value : number = 0;
scaleFactor : number = 1;
scale : number = 1.0;
transform: ImageTransform = {};


onZoom(rangeValue : number){
  if(this.value % this.scaleFactor == 0){
     this.scale = 1+this.value * 0.02;
        this.transform = {
        scale: this.scale
     };
   }
}
```